# QUERY LOOP Custom CSS: Overlay feature image on Posts Grid- UPDATED

Tags: css

As I’ve said, I’m using QUERY LOOP to create a posts grid. I want to overlay the title and excerpt of the post with the feature image. I know I have to write “position:absolute”, but I can’t complete the code correctly.

Someone gave me a code, but i couldn't use it successfully. I tried to find the correct code using online CSS generators, but no luck.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Image Overlay with Text</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1501785888041-af3ef285b470?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1470&q=80" alt="image">
            <div class="overlay-text">Your text here</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

    .image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
  background-color: #000000; 
  color: #fff; 
  padding: 10px 20px; 
  font-size: 20px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

The thing is, I’m creating this single page category grid so that you’ll always see the most recent posts. That means that whenever I upload a new post of said category, the grid will update automatically.

I thought it would be easier to find the right code if I considered it as HTML, like when customizing a child theme. I was wrong!! Can someone tell me how I should proceed?

Thanks in advance!!

PS: Grid columns are the same width and all images are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You need a bottom value for `position:absolute`, i.e.`bottom: 50%;` and you don't need the `display:` declarations.

See https://jsfiddle.net/q5xhcu3a/

Also, you should be using https://getbootstrap.com/ for grids and responsive images, as it is very easy to use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has been very helpful. The only thing I have doubts about is how to implement the code in the Querry Loop. It seems to me that the simplest thing would be to edit the page with the HTML block and add the Advanced CSS there. In the Querry Loop it is not possible for me to implement it since the code should affect several post simultaneously. From what I understand, this Code should be implemented individually in each of them, although I may be wrong. I would appreciate it if you could correct me on this point. Thanks in advance!!